# Copy a db2 schema to db2 with all tables and rename the schema?

Tags: sql, db2, database-administration

How just to copy a db2 schema with all tables and rename the schema?

windows, db2 v9.7.0.1, I am trying the command `db2 "call sysproc.admin_copy_schema('P1ADM549','H1ADM549','DDL',NULL,NULL,NULL,'ERRORS','E‌​RRORT')"` but i get

> SQLCODE: -601, SQLSTATE: 42710 - The name of the object to be created
>   is identical to the existing

Comment: DB2 version and platform?

Comment: windows, db2 v9.7.0.1, I am trying the command db2 "call sysproc.admin_copy_schema('P1ADM549','H1ADM549','DDL',NULL,NULL,NULL,'ERRORS','ERRORT')"      but i get SQLCODE: -601, SQLSTATE: 42710 - The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name

Answer (score 1):

With db2move utility it's easy, in your cause:

```
db2move source_db COPY -sn P1ADM549 -co TARGET_DB target MODE DDL_ONLY SCHEMA_MAP "((P1ADM549,H1ADM549))" [ user userid using password ] # If it's same database it isn't mandatory.
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0022655.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try the db2move utility:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/r0052064.html